# How to define a range of integers in Excel?

Tags: excel, range

Is there a range type in Excel for defining ranges of integers?

Example: Range `[1, 10]`

I could not find anything with after researching, but perhaps I am missing something

Comment: What exactly are you looking for as output?

Comment: How long does the range need to be?  I.e., maximum length?

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will return an array of integers:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for some kind of data type which would output "1-10". For example, to create a table which stores ranges of days for a project. Sorry, if I was not clear enough.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood I don't understand what you want.  In Excel, formulas output values into the cell where they are located.  If you want to "create a table", you could use a user form which collects the relevant information to create the table, and then a VBA routine which takes that information; creates the table; and outputs it to the desired location.  Or you could enter a date in some cells, and auto-fill right or down (which would auto-increment) or use a formula referring back to the relevant cell to compute a new date. To output "1-10" do you mean a date? (Jan 10 or 1 OCT), the string ...